# How can I sort class members by name in NetBeans, or another Java IDE?

Tags: java, sorting, netbeans, methods

I want to sort members by name in the source code. Is there any easy way to do it?

I'm using NetBeans, but if there is another editor that can do that, just tell me the name of it.

Comment: There is an opened issue for this for about 9 years OMG: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28294.

Comment: Status: RESOLVED FIXED

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Netbeans 8.0.1:

```
Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting -> Category: Ordering
```

[image: Netbeans member sorting]

Then:

```
Source -> Organize Members
```

[image: Netbeans member sorting]

Comment: Too bad the Ordering option is not present for PHP.

Answer (score 9):

Eclipse can do it.

Answer (score 9):

This is implemented in Netbeans 7.3: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=212528

Answer (score 3):

As @PaulCroarkin said - use eclipse, Or you can use [Jalopy](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/) as part of your build which will do all manner of magical formatting to your source files in the process (whether this is a good thing or not is open to debate)

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans lets you sort the methods in the Navigator.  Personally, I never saw the point in sorting methods in the code.  When possible I like to keep methods together that work together.  For example, the getter() and setter().  Incremental search or being able to control-click on a method to navigate to the declaration is much more useful, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

As of 6.0/6.1, this feature isn't available in the built-in tools. The "Navigator" view is intended to give you an ordered index of your members. To see the Navigator, go to Window->Navigating->Navigator or hit Control-F7.

Consider submitting a [feature enhancement to Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/community/issues.html).

Answer (score 0):

For C/C++ mode, right click on the method name inside the Navigator window, then there's choice of "Sort by Name" or "Sort by Source", choose the one you like :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the easy way to do it in NetBeans:

1. Go to the Tools tab and chose Options.
   The option Window should appear.
2. Click on Editor and chose the Formatting Tab.
3. Select Ordering for Category. 
   Ordering is the last element from the drop down Category list.
4. Uncheck the Sort Members By Visibility field.
   At this point only the "Sort Members in Groups Alphabetically" should be checked.
5. Click Apply and exit the Option window.
   Now you globally set to sort members alphabetically.
6. Open or Select the source file you want to sort the members.
7. Click the Source Tab (upper right corner) and chose Organize Members.

And that is it. Your source file should have the members sorted alphabetically.